# No audio output 12.04

Tags: sound

I installed Precise 12.04.  Installation went well and system worked fine for some time, but now no sound or ability to record from microphone.

Comment: check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Answer (score -1):

Try installing a new audio driver. You can check out [*Realtek*](http://www.realtek.com.tw/default.aspx) for some drivers. Just click "*Downloads*" and then click "*High Definition Audio Codecs*".
Then scroll down and you should see drivers for Linux.

Comment: Realtek? Why Realtek?

Comment: I used Realtek for my audio and they work.

Comment: "Audio drivers available for download from the Realtek website are general drivers for our audio ICs, and may not offer the customizations made by your system/motherboard manufacturer. To be sure you obtain the full features/customizations provided in your original audio product, please download the latest drivers from your system/motherboard manufacturer's website."